# Is there any way to do something like DNAT but keeps the original IP?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking

I have following servers

- Linux Host server A, 10.0.0.2

  - qemu-kvm guest vmA1, 192.168.0.2
  - qemu-kvm guest vmA2, 192.168.0.3
- Linux Host server B, 10.0.1.2

  - qemu-kvm guest vmB1, 192.168.1.2
  - qemu-kvm guest vmB2, 192.168.1.3

Hosts network is 10.0.0.0/16, and there's no route for 192.168.0.0/16, and I do not have access to network router, so I'm not able to add route in router.

Host and guests are using bridge network, so vm1 and communicate with vm2. And hosts can communicate with each other too.

Now I would like to make VMs in different hosts can communicate, for example, 192.168.1.2 can ping 192.168.0.2

So I add following iptables in server B:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -j DNAT -d 192.168.0.2 --to-destination 10.0.0.2
```

Then 192.168.1.2 indeed can ping 192.168.0.2

I thought I have made it, but turned out it's not.

The packet just goes to 10.0.0.2, not 192.168.0.2.

If I `ssh 192.168.0.2`, I found that I'm ssh 10.0.0.2 in fact.

So I think it is because the destination IP was changed by iptables, so the packet will never go to 192.168.0.2

Since I'm not able to add route in router, how can I achieve this?

I'm thinking is there any way to make a packet from 192.168.1.2 to 192.168.0.2, first `wrapped` with destination IP 10.0.0.2 by some kind of protocol or software, and sent to the network, and when the packet arrived to 10.0.0.2, `unwrap` the destination IP 10.0.0.2 and restore to original IP 192.168.0.2 by this protocol or software, so the packet will go to 192.168.0.2.

This is just something I thought, maybe there are other methods to achieve this.

Comment: The technology which "wraps" (*encapsulates*) a packet on one side and "unwraps" (*decapsulates*) it on other side of the *tunnel* is called VPN. But you will need configure additional routes on your VMs — which is already not very good, because their gateways *are* places where such routes should normally be configured. // Having said that, please remember that in enterprise environment (which is what we are talking about here) you don't invent murky schemes, but go and request appropriate permissions to do your work, or make responsible people to do their work if it is not your area.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thank you. So with VPN, I can achieve what I want? BTW: request permission to operate on gateway is impossible as this  is a managed network on third party infrastructure

Comment: So what are default gateways for the VMs? What are their addresses and where they are? (Do your hosts provide Internet access to VMs with NAT? Are your hosts deployed within a single L2 segment?) Don't get it wrong, I am searching for easiest and most efficient solution and I want to see if you can just install one more route on each host.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov The default gateway is 10.0.0.1, we can create VMs on subnet 10.0.0.0/16, the VM created can access internet(with NAT, I think). I do not know L2 segment deployment.

Comment: I mean how currently *your VMs* from 192.168.x.x access the Internet? Obviously we don't want to break that, because what also will break is the access to them *from* the Internet. If you see on each host MAC address of other one (check `ip neigh show`), they're is the same L2 segment.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I'm using virsh's default nat network. so 192.168 can access internet

Comment: I don't know what's "virsh default nat network", when I last used libvirt (10 years ago) I didn't used any default networks, so please provide details how this network is set up. What addresses you are using as gateways? Which system has these addresses assigned — host? It's host who performs NAT for them?

Answer (score 0):

*Notice, there will be if's; you still didn't provided much information about your network, so I had to cover different cases. In the best case, the one provides the full network diagram with all the important details (addresses, how the NAT is set up and so on). Depending on the details, the working solution might be **significantly** simpler, as simple as just adding two routes on hosts.*

Generic safe solution would be:

1. Install additional VM on each host, which will have access to each other's single UDP port. If there are any NAT between them, you need to forward that port. (Really only one needs the port to be accessible from the other, but your general structure seems to be symmetric and I suggest to make this symmetric too.)
2. Each of those VMs also need to have an interface in their corresponding bridge and IP address in it. Let it be "192.168.x.254" for the sake of my description. On other VMs on the host who need to reach VMs of the other host, you should install a route through local VPN VM: VMs from `192.168.1.0/24` should have `ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 192.168.1.254`.

Notice that those might be the same interface: the VM can access other VM using a single address `192.168.x.254`.

3. Install WireGuard on both VPN VMs and setup a tunnel: on the `192.168.<a>.254`,

```
ip link add dev wg0 type wireguard
ip address add dev wg0 192.168.2.<a> peer 192.168.2.<b>
wg set wg0 listen-port 51820 private-key /path/to/private-key peer <key-b> allowed-ips 192.168.<b>.0/24 endpoint <ip-b>:51820
```

where `<a>` and `<b>` are 0 and 1 for one VM and reverse for another.

`<ip-0>` and `<ip-1>` are addresses that are they should use to access each other's UDP port, 51820 on both in this example. If there is NAT, those will be addresses of the NAT box (for example, if NAT is performed by the host these are addresses of hosts).

4. Set up routes on those VMs: `ip route add 192.168.<b>.0/24 via 192.168.2.<b>` on VM `<a>`.

---

If NAT is performed by hosts, you may set up tunnel directly on hosts and the configuration will be simpler, because you'll need no additional VMs and no additional routes on existing VMs.

If hosts are in the same L2, you may just add two routes on hosts: `ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 10.0.1.2` (and reverse on the other one), and set up NATs so they will not translate those packets. This is most simple and efficient solution.